# Error while compiling Python-Kivy in eclipse (Ubuntu14.04)

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, kivy, kivy-language

I install python-kivy package on Ubuntu-14.04. But while compiling it in eclipse it gives errors as follows. I think its related to X11, graphics related so any one have idea that How to resolve this Python-Kivy related error.

```
enter code here[INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in home/nrcfoss/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-04_10.txt
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 157 symbols loaded
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pygame, img_pil, img_gif 
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] Loading kv </home/nrcfoss/Documents/EclipseWorkSpace/KIVY/test.kv>
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] kv </home/nrcfoss/Documents/EclipseWorkSpace/KIVY/test.kv> not found
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[WARNING           ] [WinPygame   ] Video: failed (multisamples=2)
[WARNING           ] [WinPygame   ] trying without antialiasing
[ERROR             ] [Window      ] Unable to use pygame
[ERROR             ] [Window      ] The module raised an important error: "Couldn't find matching GLX visual"
Exception kivy.core.CoreCriticalException: CoreCriticalException("Couldn't find matching GLX visual",) in 'kivy.properties.dpi2px' ignored
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[WARNING           ] [WinPygame   ] SDL wrapper failed to import!
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <sdl> (import error)
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <x11> (import error)
[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: I checked that PyGame is properly installed and x11vnc, libgstreamer0.10-dev are also installed but still facing the same problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103701/kivy-python-error-while-running-hello-world

Comment: tried that before but not working

Comment: That error is usually due to your computer having a very poor graphics chip, or poor video card drivers. Your card and drivers must support OpenGL ES 2 for Kivy apps to work. If you are running this in a virtual machine, make sure you have turned on 3D acceleration for that VM.

Comment: tried to install all dependencies related to python-kivy and OpenGL ES i.e X11 related packages, still doesn't fount any satisfactory solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: so I need to run this in virtualEnv. but my PC have graphics chip My machine is HP-ALLInONE.

Comment: Your kivy version is very old, I recommend upgrading it (and also using SDL2, not pygame), though if this issue is opengl related it won't help with that.

Comment: Can you please tell How to upgrade kivy because I tried to upgrade kivy-1.8 to 1.9 on Ubuntu-14.04 but its not working so please help me.